# NoMethodError: undefined method `bindings' for java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, puma

we're working on a ruby on rails (4.2.8) application which is running on jruby-1.7.25. It really is time to update this mummy to the latest version 9.1.7.0. We did that and for most of my colleagues it works out fine. But - guess what - not for me. Before posting my question here, I made sure that:

- I have the same setup
- Same DB content
- The exactly same code

as the others, but I still get that stupid error which is
`java.lang.NullPointerException` and that's really all, the app is spitting out on any request.

I was digging for the last hours and found out, that the real issue is getting lost in the depth of logging. Finally I found, that I will see the real cause if I add a `puts` in the file `vendor/jruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb` like:

```
class ShowExceptions
  FAILSAFE_RESPONSE = [500, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' },
    ["500 Internal Server Error\n" \
     "If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web " \
     "application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what " \
     "went wrong."]]

  def initialize(app, exceptions_app)
    @app = app
    @exceptions_app = exceptions_app
  end

  def call(env)
    @app.call(env)
  rescue Exception => exception
    puts "EXCEPTION: #{exception.inspect}\n@app: #{@app.inspect}\nENV: #{env.inspect}"
    if env['action_dispatch.show_exceptions'] == false
      raise exception
    else
      render_exception(env, exception)
    end
  end
```

The output is:

```
EXCEPTION: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `bindings' for java.lang.NullPointerException:Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException
```

`@app` and `env` print out kilobytes of data which probably do not help. Honestly, I'm kind of stuck here. How can it work on other machines while it fails on mine? Has anyone of you had a similar issue or any idea what causes this trouble?

Ah, some version infos

- Puma: `* Version 3.7.1 (jruby 9.1.7.0 - ruby 2.3.1), codename: Snowy Sagebrush`
- jruby: `jruby 9.1.7.0 (2.3.1) 2017-01-11 68056ae Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.79-b02 on 1.7.0_79-b15 +jit [darwin-x86_64]`
- java: `java version "1.7.0_79"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)`
- Mac OSX: `10.12.3 (16D32)`

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: SOLVED: When exporting the following JRUBY_OPTS, everything goes green: `export JRUBY_OPTS="-J-Xmx4096m -Xcompile.invokedynamic=false -J-XX:+TieredCompilation -J-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -J-noverify -Xcompile.mode=OFF"` - 

while mainly `-Xcompile.mode=OFF` does the trick